# Как нарисовать линии на прямоугольнике при помощи OpenGL

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Не знаю как нарисовать такие линии как на картинке см.скрин https://prnt.sc/8vNPkBONgSeV на прямоугольнике при помощи OpenGL C++.

Вот сам код

```
#include "my_paint.h"
#include <QtOpenGL>
#include <GL/gl.h>
My_paint::My_paint()
{
    resize(450,250);
}
void My_paint::initializeGL()
{
    qglClearColor(QColor(128, 128, 0));
}
void My_paint::resizeGL(int nWidth, int nHeight)
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
       glLoadIdentity();

       glViewport(0,0, (GLint)nWidth, (GLint)nHeight);
       glOrtho(0,200,100,0,-1,1);
}
void My_paint::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    qglColor(QColor(128, 0, 0));
    glVertex2d(20,20);
    glVertex2d(180,20);
    glVertex2d(180,80);
    glVertex2d(20,80);
    glEnd();
}
void My_paint::scene()
{

}
```

Comment: Видимо вам понадобится соответствующая текстура с кирпичной кладкой.

Comment: Уточните, а в чем сложность? Можете по координатам просто нарисовать, например.